# BibTex entry for a co-written chapter in a PhD thesis?

Tags: bibtex, citing

I'm trying to cite a co-written chapter in [a PhD thesis](http://urn.kb.se/resolve?urn=urn:nbn:se:su:diva-172106) and can't decide what entry type that I should use. My best guess as of yet is to use `@incollection` and specify the PhD candidate as an editor, but that seems a bit odd... Do you have any suggestions?

```
@incollection{FoltynOlsson2019,
  author = {Foltyn, Richard and Olsson, Jonna},
  title = {Subjective life expectancies, time preference heterogeneity and wealth inequality},
  booktitle = {Work, wealth, and well-being: Essays in macroeconomics},
  publisher = {Institute for International Economic Studies},
  year = {2019},
  editor = {Olsson, Jonna},
  series = {Monograph Series},
  number = {104},
  type = {PhD thesis},
  chapter = {4},
  pages = {193-240},
  address = {Stockholm},
  month = {September}
}
```

Comment: Interesting question. `@inbook` might work slightly better (mainly because you won't get to see "editor"), but this will depend on your bibliography style. If I hadn't known that `Work, wealth, and well-being: Essays in macroeconomics` is a dissertation, I would have definitely said that `@incollection` is 100% the correct type.

Comment: In any case `number = {Monograph Series},` looks fishy.

Comment: I agree with @moewe. It seems somewhat odd that a co-written chapter of a thesis wouldn't have an independent published source elsewhere (although there's one famous dissertation in my field that was actually co-written, so who am I to say!). My intuition would be to use the `@inbook`. This way you can have `bookauthor` instead of `editor`. This is really the kind of thing that only `biblatex` can handle decently I suspect.

Comment: @moewe I fixed the `number`. Don't sleep and type :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is tricky. The correct entry not only depends on what you think would be sensible output but to some extent also on the style you use.

Had I not known that *Work, wealth, and well-being: Essays in macroeconomics* was published as a doctoral thesis I would have been pretty confident that `@incollection` is the right choice. The four chapters were written by different authors (chapter 1 by Jonna Olsson, chapter 2 by Timo Boppart, Per Krusell and Jonna Olsson, chapter 3 and chapter 4 by Richard Foltyn and Jonna Olsson), so `@inbook` doesn't quite feel right for me. In general the rule of thumb is that an `@incollection` is contained in a collection, which is usually compiled by an `editor` and consists of multiple (possibly related papers) by – usually – different sets of authors. An `@inbook`, on the other hand, is a chapter/section of a `@book`, which was written in its entirety by the same set of authors.

The standard BibTeX styles (and also the standard `natbib` styles) use the `type` field in `@incollection` to give the type of the "chapter", so

```
type = {PhD thesis},
```

will probably not result in the desired output. The `biblatex` standard styles completely ignore `type` for `@incollection`. So the `note` field may give better results than `type` here.

```
note = {PhD thesis},
```

All in all I would probably end up with an entry looking pretty much like the one suggested in the question

```
@incollection{FoltynOlsson2019,
  author    = {Foltyn, Richard and Olsson, Jonna},
  title     = {Subjective life expectancies, time preference heterogeneity and wealth inequality},
  booktitle = {Work, wealth, and well-being: Essays in macroeconomics},
  editor    = {Olsson, Jonna},
  year      = {2019},
  month     = sep,
  series    = {Institute for International Economic Studies Monograph Series},
  number    = {104},
  note      = {PhD thesis},
  chapter   = {4},
  pages     = {193-240},
  publisher = {Stockholm University},
  address   = {Stockholm},
}
```

The main issues with the output one gets from this entry is probably that Jonna Olsson is shown as the "editor" of the complete work (the dissertation), which is probably not a completely unfair characterisation if you look at this work as a collection, but just doesn't feel right if you look at the complete work as a thesis.

---

With the `biblatex` standard styles `@inbook` gives slightly better results because you can use `bookauthor` instead of `editor`.

```
@inbook{FoltynOlsson2019,
  author       = {Foltyn, Richard and Olsson, Jonna},
  title        = {Subjective life expectancies, time preference heterogeneity and wealth inequality},
  booktitle    = {Work, wealth, and well-being},
  booksubtitle = {Essays in macroeconomics},
  bookauthor   = {Olsson, Jonna},
  date         = {2019-09},
  series       = {Institute for International Economic Studies Monograph Series},
  number       = {104},
  note         = {PhD thesis},
  chapter      = {4},
  pages        = {193-240},
  publisher    = {Stockholm University},
  location     = {Stockholm},
}
```